# creating copy button for selected text

Tags: flutter

I have selectable widget. I need when I select a text I can do copy programmatically from a button in Flutter. i.e. I need to select a text and then use separate button to copy the selected text

I found method for copying a text from textfeild but I did not find any thing like what I need

Comment: are you looking for this https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/EditableText/contextMenuBuilder.html?

Comment: give more info about your task.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Clipboard` class.

Copy text as below.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

await Clipboard.setData(ClipboardData(text: 'abc'));
```

And get text as below.

```dart
final text = await Clipboard.getData(Clipboard.kTextPlain);
```